# Working with NULL Date Fields

Tags: sql-server-2016, null, date, isnull

I have a derived VARCHAR date field that I need to use for deriving another field, based off of whether or not the date field has a value.  The derived date field is called "AmortDate" and I'm attempting the following:

```
CASE WHEN 'AmortDate' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END AS "IsAmortizing?'
```

I've tried several different variations (<> NULL, <>'', IS NOT NULL)

```
CASE WHEN ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE = '0' THEN ''
WHEN ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE = '1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule = '999' AND ln.TERM_IN_MONTHS = '0' AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_NBR = '1' AND lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst <>''
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst,120)
 WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule = '999' AND ln.TERM_IN_MONTHS = '0' AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_NBR = '1' AND lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst = ''
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ln.DATE_EXPECT_PAYOFF,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule = '999' AND ln.TERM_IN_MONTHS = '999' AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_NBR = '1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ln.DATE_EXPECT_PAYOFF,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule NOT IN('1','999') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE = '0' AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT = '0'
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ln.DATE_EXPECT_PAYOFF,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule NOT IN('1','999') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE IN('1','2','3') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT = '0'
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule NOT IN('1','999') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE IN('1','2','3') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT > 0
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),lpsf.psDatePmtDueFirst,120)
WHEN lpsf.psNbrPmtsThisSchedule NOT IN('1','999') AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE = '6' AND ln.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT = '0'
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ln.DATE_MATURITY_NEXT,120)
ELSE ''
END AS AmortDate
```

Based off of the results of the derived AmortDate field above, I need to create another calculated field:

```
CASE WHEN AmortDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS 'IsAmortizing'
```

Comment: Single quotes mean 'AmortDate' is a string, so it's always NOT NULL.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] as I suspect you've got a join and where you're expecting rows with NULL values to exist actually don't exist at all, but I won't be sure without additional context.

Answer (score 2):

Remove string delimiter from column names:

```
CASE WHEN AmortDate IS NOT NULL 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END AS IsAmortizing?
```

Otherwise you are testning whether the string AmortDate is null.

If you need to quote an identifier, "Is.." is standard, sql server uses [Is.. ] and MYSQL uses `Is...`

```
CASE WHEN AmortDate IS NOT NULL 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END AS "IsAmortizing?"
```

EDIT:

Renaming (AS ...) happens last, so you need to add a nesting level if you want to reference an alias:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN AmortDate IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS "IsAmortizing?", ...
FROM (
    SELECT ... AS AmortDate, ...
    FROM ...
) AS T
```

Comment: For MYSQL it should be Backticks

Comment: The problem is that the 'AmortDate' is a calculated field in the query and isn't coming from a table.  When I remove the '' string delimiters, then it says that it doesn't recognize the field.

Comment: In that case you must put in the CASE as the field is calculated Example CASE WHEN Field1 + Field2 IS NOT NULL.....You could put the deficiency of your table or your query to help you better

Comment: @Lennart Would it be easier if I were to just make a temp table out of the AmortDate and bring it in that way?

Comment: Hard to tell what what is easier without knowing more details. Have you considered a view or a generated column for AmortDate?